# Prevent host shutting down when remotely logged in

Tags: server, ssh, suspend, client

I have a laptop I'm setting up with SSH open server. It works great after I wake it up with magic packet and login with:

```
ssh user@host -Y
```

The problem is the laptop is designed to blank screen after five minutes and suspend after 20 minutes of inactivity.

How can I have a script (or canned package) send fake signals to server as if a user was typing on system? This way host system won't suspend after 20 minutes unless there were 20 minutes of inactivity on the client.

When simulating user activity I'd like the screen blanking to be honored as if there were no user activity on host. I just don't want laptop to suspend when remotely logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a script called `ssh-activity` that:

- Monitors output from `w` command every 60 seconds.
- If one or more remote logged in users have typed something then simulate user activity with `dbus` call.
- If activity would unblank screen then immediately blank it on server.
- Honor setting for screen blanking time and force blanking at appropriate time.
- If remote user doesn't type anything in terminal, broadcast messages (using `wall` command) warning of shutdown or suspend.

### `ssh-activity` script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: ssh-activity
# PATH: /mnt/e/bin
# DESC: When ssh client types in terminal send dbus method for user activity.

# CALL: Must run on host. Shaould be called in startup applications after user
#       logs into host desktop. Broadcast message when inactive that system
#       going down in 60, 30, 15, 10, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0 minute(s).

# PARM: --n (-no-blank-lock) and -d (--debug)

# DATE: June 21, 2020. Modified: Original Version.

# NOTE: After updating run: scp /mnt/e/bin/ssh-activity dell:/mnt/e/bin

#       For Debugging:
#           on host run: ssh-activity -d | tee ssh-activity.log
#           on client run: while : ; do echo "==========  ssh-activity.log $(date)  ==========" ; tail ssh-activity.log ; sleep 60 ; done

# Global constants
export LANG=C       # Force english names for sed & grep searches
SLEEP_SECS=60       # Seconds to sleep between 'w -ish' command usage
REMOTE="192.168.0"  # What we 'grep' for in 'w -ish' output
fDebug=false        # When debug is on issue progress messages
fNoBlankLock=false  # Don't blank or lock screen

ParseParms () {

    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
        key="$1"
        case $key in
            -d|--debug)
                fDebug=true
                echo "Development Mode = $fDebug"
                shift # past argument
                ;;
            -n|--no-blank-lock)
                fNoBlankLock=true
                shift # past argument
                ;;
            *)  # unknown option
                echo "Usage: ssh-activity -d (--debug) -n (--no-blank-lock)"
                exit
            ;;
        esac
    done
} # ParseParms

# Must have the xprintidle package.
command -v xprintidle >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 \
        "'xprintidle' package required but it is not installed.  Aborting."; \
        exit 3; }

# Global gsettings set by Init () function need to control screen & suspending
GsAcTimeOut=0   # idle seconds until system sleeps (0=never for all settings)
GsIdleDelay=0   # idle seconds until screen blanks (a good thing for server)
GsLockDelay=0   # idle seconds until screen locks (a bad thing if logged in)
GsLockEnabled=0 # is lock screen enabled? ('false' overrides GsLockDelay)
fOneTime=false  # for displaying debugging information one time only

Init () {

    # gsettings required to know when system shuts down due to xidle time
    GsAcTimeOut=$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power \
                        sleep-inactive-ac-timeout)

    # gsettings required for blanking and locking screen when no host activity
    if [[ $fNoBlankLock == false ]] ; then
        GsIdleDelay=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay)
        # Cut out rightside value from 'uint32 0'
        GsIdleDelay="${GsIdleDelay##* }"
        [[ $GsIdleDelay -eq 0 ]] && GsIdleDelay=999999
        GsLockDelay=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay)
        GsLockDelay="${GsLockDelay##* }"
        [[ $GsLockDelay -eq 0 ]] && GsLockDelay=999999
        GsLockEnabled=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled)
    fi

    if [[ $fDebug == true && $fOneTime == false ]] ; then
        echo "$0 started at: $(date)"
        echo "GsAcTimeOut: $GsAcTimeOut"
        echo "GsIdleDelay: $GsIdleDelay"
        echo "GsLockDelay: $GsLockDelay"
        echo "GsLockEnabled: $GsLockEnabled"
        fOneTime=true
    fi

} # Init

GetWish () {
    # 'w' command '-ish' arguments (--ip-adddr, --short, --no-header) returns:
    #       rick     pts/21   192.168.0.12      4.00s sshd: rick [priv] 

    local ArrEntCnt ArrCols ArrRows CheckSum i

    ArrCols=5
    WishArr=( $(w -ish | grep "$REMOTE" | tr -s " " | \
             cut -d' ' -f1-"$ArrCols") )
    # The fifth column on each row repurposed to be idle time seconds
    ArrEntCnt="${#WishArr[@]}"
    [[ $ArrEntCnt -lt "$ArrCols" ]] && return 1  # No remote users

    ArrRows=$(( $ArrEntCnt / ArrCols ))
    CheckSum=$(( ArrRows * ArrCols ))
    # Error possible if 'w -ish' command breaks down
    [[ $ArrEntCnt -ne "$CheckSum" ]] && { echo CheckSum failed ; \
                                                return 2 ; }

    LowestSeconds=999999

    for (( i=0; i<ArrEntCnt; i=i+ArrCols )) ; do
        # Time formatted as DDdays, HH:MMm, MM:SSs & SS.CC convert to Seconds
        WishSeconds "${WishArr[i+3]}" Seconds
        WishArr[i+4]=$Seconds   # Store in repurposed array column # 5
        [[ $Seconds -lt "$LowestSeconds" ]] && LowestSeconds="$Seconds"

        [[ $fDebug == true ]] && echo "${WishArr[i]} ${WishArr[i+1]} \
${WishArr[i+2]} Wish Time: ${WishArr[i+3]} Seconds: ${WishArr[i+4]} "
    done

    return 0

} # GetWish

: <<'END'
/* ------------ NOTES  --------------------------------------------------------

$ w -ish

rick     tty7     :0                2days /sbin/upstart --user
rick     pts/21   192.168.0.12      4.00s sshd: rick [priv] 
AND THEN LATER ON....
rick     pts/21   192.168.0.12     44.00s sshd: rick [priv]
rick     pts/21   192.168.0.12      1:24  sshd: rick [priv]
rick     pts/21   192.168.0.12      2:04  sshd: rick [priv]

From: https://serverfault.com/questions/302455/
      how-to-read-the-idle-column-in-the-output-of-the-linux-w-command/
      302462#302462

From the man page:

    The standard format is DDdays, HH:MMm, MM:SS or SS.CCs .
    if the times are greater than 2 days, 1hour, or 1 minute respectively.
    so your output is MM:SS (>1m and <1 hour).

---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
END

WishSeconds () {

    # PARM 1: 'w -ish' command idle time 44.00s, 5:10, 1:28m, 3days, etc.
    #      2: Variable name (no $ is used) to receive idle time in seconds

    # NOTE: Idle time resets to zero when user types something in terminal.
    #       A looping job calling a command doesn't reset idle time.

    local Wish Unit1 Unit2
    Wish="$1"
    declare -n Seconds=$2

    # Leading 0 is considered octal value in bash. Change ':09' to ':9'
    Wish="${Wish/:0/:}"

    if [[ "$Wish" == *"days"* ]] ; then
        Unit1="${Wish%%days*}"
        Seconds=$(( Unit1 * 86400 ))
    elif [[ "$Wish" == *"m"* ]] ; then
        Unit1="${Wish%%m*}"
        Unit2="${Unit1##*:}"
        Unit1="${Unit1%%:*}"
        Seconds=$(( (Unit1 * 3600) + (Unit2 * 60) ))
    elif [[ "$Wish" == *"s"* ]] ; then
        Seconds="${Wish%%.*}"
    else
        Unit1="${Wish%%:*}"
        Unit2="${Wish##*:}"
        Seconds=$(( (Unit1 * 60) + Unit2 ))
    fi

} # WishSeconds

HostShutDownMessage () {

    # Send wall message 60, 30, 15, 10, 5, 3, 2 and 1 minute(s) before shutdown

    [[ $GsAcTimeOut == 0 ]] && return           # System never shuts down
    MinutesLeft=$(( ( GsAcTimeOut / 60 ) - ( IdleSeconds / 60 ) ))
    case $MinutesLeft in
        60|30|15|10|5|3|2|1)
            [[ $fDebug == true ]] && \
                echo "'wall' broadcast: shutdown in: $MinutesLeft minute(s)."
            wall "If no activity, shutdown in: $MinutesLeft minute(s)." ;;
        0)
            [[ $fDebug == true ]] && \
                echo "Host system shutdown at: $(date)"
            wall "HOST SYSTEM SHUTDOWN at: $(date)" ;;
    esac

} # HostShutDownMessage

SSC_Result=""
ScreenSaverCommand () {

    # Send dbus method to screen saver
    Parm1="$1"  # GetActiveTime, Inhibit, Throttle, Lock, UnThrottle, Unihibit,
                # GetActive, SetActive (requires true), SimulateUserActivity,
                # GetSessionIdleTime (broken!)
    Parm2="$2"  # Optional, a value like 'true'

    # If parameter 2 not passed force it to be unset, instead of null parm    
    SSC_Result=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.ScreenSaver \
                  --object-path /org/gnome/ScreenSaver \
                  --method org.gnome.ScreenSaver."$Parm1" ${Parm2:+"$Parm2"})
    [[ $fDebug == true ]] &&  echo Screen Saver Command: $Parm1 $Parm2   \
                                   Result: $SSC_Result

} # ScreenSaverCommand

CheckToBlankOrLock () {

    # Comments from above
    # GsAcTimeOut=0   # idle seconds until system sleeps (0=never for all settings)
    # GsIdleDelay=0   # idle seconds until screen blanks (a good thing for server)
    # GsLockDelay=0   # idle seconds until screen locks (a bad thing if logged in)
    # GsLockEnabled=0 # is lock screen enabled? ('false' overrides GsLockDelay)

    [[ $fDebug == true ]] && echo IdleSeconds: $IdleSeconds \
                                  ResetIdleSeconds: $ResetIdleSeconds

    # Is screen blanked ?
    ScreenSaverCommand "GetActive"
    if [[ $SSC_Result == *"false"* ]] ; then
        # Screen is not blanked. We may have to blank it though
        ScreenSaverCommand "SimulateUserActivity"
        NewIdle="$(xprintidle)"
        [[ $NewIdle -gt 1000 ]] && echo "ERROR: Idle time not reset: $NewIdle"
        # Screen is not blanked, check if we should blank it
        if [[ $ResetIdleSeconds -gt $GsIdleDelay ]] ; then
            [[ $fDebug == true ]] && echo Forcing screen blank
            ScreenSaverCommand "SetActive" true
        else
            : # We didn't blank screen but it is blank now from host inactivity
            # No need to simulate activity while user is active
        fi
    else
        : # Screen is blanked before simulation, blank it afterwards
#        [[ $fDebug == true ]] && echo Simiulating activity and blanking screen
        ScreenSaverCommand "SimulateUserActivity"
        ScreenSaverCommand "SetActive" true
        NewIdle="$(xprintidle)"
        [[ $NewIdle -gt 1000 ]] && echo "ERROR: Idle time not reset: $NewIdle"
    fi
    
    # TODO: Check if screen is locked.    

} # CheckToBlankOrLock

ResetIdleSeconds=0  # Total idle seconds we've invoked not host activity
SavedBlankSetting=false

SimulateUserActivity () {

    # Is screen blanking and locking check turned off with parameters?
    if [[ $fNoBlankLock == true ]] ; then
        ScreenSaverCommand "SimulateUserActivity"
        NewIdle="$(xprintidle)"
        [[ $NewIdle -gt 1000 ]] && echo "ERROR: Idle time not reset: $NewIdle"
        return 0
    fi

    if [[ $IdleSeconds -lt "$LowestSeconds" ]] ; then
        # User activity on host is resetting idle time so no need for us to.
        ResetIdleSeconds=0
    else
        # xidle seconds is greater than or equal to remote terminal activity
        ResetIdleSeconds=$(( ResetIdleSeconds + IdleSeconds ))
        CheckToBlankOrLock  # Each time called also simulates user activity
    fi

} # SimulateUserActivity

main () {

    ParseParms "$@"

    LowestSeconds=999999
    if [[ $fDebug == true ]] ; then
        LoopCnt=10   # Fake user inactivity for ten minutes
    fi

    while : ; do    # Loop forever
        Init        # Support user changing idle time settings on server
        GetWish     # Get idle times using 'w -ish'

        # Is a local user working at server or did we set last idle activity?
        IdleSeconds=$(( $(xprintidle) / 1000 ))    # returns milliseconds

        [[ $fDebug == true ]] &&  echo IdleSeconds: $IdleSeconds \
                                       LowestSeconds: $LowestSeconds
        # If xprintidle time is less than SLEEP_SECS yes there is
        # If xprintidle time is equal to last override time then no

        # If Wish Seconds < SLEEP_SECS there was activity from remote user
        if [[ $LowestSeconds -lt "$SLEEP_SECS" ]] ; then
            SimulateUserActivity
            IdleSeconds=0
        else
            IdleSeconds=$(( IdleSeconds + SLEEP_SECS ))
            # Send wall message 10, 5, 3, 2 and 1 minutes before disconnect.
            HostShutDownMessage
        fi

        sleep "$SLEEP_SECS"
    done
} # main

main "$@"
```

### Sample results on host when `ssh-activity -d` used

```bash
==========  ssh-activity.log Sun Jun 21 20:09:36 MDT 2020  ==========
IdleSeconds: 300 LowestSeconds: 338
rick pts/1 192.168.0.12 Wish Time: 1:42m Seconds: 6120 
rick pts/19 192.168.0.12 Wish Time: 6:38 Seconds: 398 
IdleSeconds: 360 LowestSeconds: 398
rick pts/1 192.168.0.12 Wish Time: 1:43m Seconds: 6180 
rick pts/19 192.168.0.12 Wish Time: 7:38 Seconds: 458 
IdleSeconds: 420 LowestSeconds: 458
rick pts/1 192.168.0.12 Wish Time: 1:44m Seconds: 6240 
rick pts/19 192.168.0.12 Wish Time: 8:38 Seconds: 518 
IdleSeconds: 480 LowestSeconds: 518
                                                                               
Broadcast message from rick@dell (somewhere) (Sun Jun 21 20:09:43 2020):       
                                                                               
If no activity, shutdown in: 10 minute(s).
```

### Remote terminal output when shutting down

If remote user doesn't type anything in terminal then these messages appears 60, 30, 15, 10, 5, 3, 2, 1 and 0 minute(s) before shutdown (suspend in my case).

```bash
Broadcast message from rick@dell (somewhere) (Sun Jun 21 20:38:45 2020):       
                                                                               
If no activity, shutdown in: 5 minute(s).
                                                                               
                                                                               
Broadcast message from rick@dell (somewhere) (Sun Jun 21 20:40:45 2020):       
                                                                               
If no activity, shutdown in: 3 minute(s).
                                                                               
                                                                               
Broadcast message from rick@dell (somewhere) (Sun Jun 21 20:41:45 2020):       
                                                                               
If no activity, shutdown in: 2 minute(s).
                                                                               
                                                                               
Broadcast message from rick@dell (somewhere) (Sun Jun 21 20:42:45 2020):       
                                                                               
If no activity, shutdown in: 1 minute(s).
                                                                               
                                                                               
Broadcast message from rick@dell (somewhere) (Sun Jun 21 20:43:45 2020):       
                                                                               
HOST SYSTEM SHUTDOWN at: Sun Jun 21 20:43:45 MDT 2020
```